# Validar política de senha no Active Directory usando Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard

Tags: asp.net-core, validação, active-directory

Estou desenvolvendo uma API em .NET 6 que precisa ser hospedada em um ambiente Linux. Estou utilizando o pacote Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard para interagir com o Active Directory. A minha necessidade é validar se um usuário pode definir uma nova senha no Active Directory, com a restrição de que a nova senha não pode ser igual às duas últimas senhas utilizadas. Essa política já está configurada no Active Directory.

O problema é que, quando chamo o método para alterar a senha, ele permite definir senhas anteriores e não me retorna mensagem de erro, mesmo a política estando configurada no AD.

O código que implementei até o momento é o seguinte:

```
public async Task<DirectoryResponse> AlterarSenha(RedefinirSenhaModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                var ldapIdentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(Ad.Dominio);
                using (var connection = new LdapConnection(ldapIdentifier))
                {
                    connection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
                    connection.Credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Ad.Usuario, Ad.Senha);

                    var entry = (await BuscarUsuarioAdPorCpf(model.Cpf.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (entry != null && entry.Attributes.Contains("displayName") && entry.Attributes["displayName"].Count > 0)
                    {
                        var newPasswordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(model.Senha);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.EmailFuncional))
                        {
                            var modifyRequest = new ModifyRequest(entry.DistinguishedName, DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace, "userPassword", newPasswordBytes);
                            connection.SendRequest(modifyRequest);
                        }
                    }
                    else { _notificador.Notificar(new Notificacao("Usuario não encontrado no Ad")); }
                }

                return null;
            }
            catch (LdapException) { throw; }
        }
```

Espero que a API do Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard me retorne que a senha não atende à política de requisitos ao alterar a senha para uma senha antiga que foi utilizada pelo usuário.